# I want to use Percent Pipe only for showing % symbol. not need to convert

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

I want to use Percent pipe just for displaying the value with % symbol. Currently backend performing the conversion and giving data. my duty just displaying the figure with % symbol. but while I using 'percent' pipe which converting the value again to percentage format. I want him to stop converting again but need % symbol of him. how to solve this issue.?
`{{ row[attr.uniqKey] ? (row[attr.uniqKey] | percent) : '' }}`

Comment: Create your own pipe, which add % symbol. This is the easiest solution. :)

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations

Answer (score 1):

If you check the official documentation of [percent pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe) you can see that main functionality of percent pipe is to convert the data into percentage value not to add **%** symbol

you can add **%** by following way

**1) ADD IN HTML** (esiest way)

```
{{ row[attr.uniqKey] }} %
```

**2) CREATE CUSTOM PIPE FOR ADD % SYMBOL**

**percentageSymbol.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'percentagesymbol'
})
export class PercentagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    return value + '%';
  }
}
```

Use this pipe in html

```
{{ row[attr.uniqKey] | percentagesymbol }}
```

**3) Request to the backend developer to add % symbol at the end of the value so user value itself have a % symbol**

Answer (score 1):

if your value is a number, you can divide if by 100 before using the percent pipe

```
(row[attr.uniqKey] / 100 | percent)
```

if your value is 50.00, this will show 50% :-)